# Haskell more elegant conversion from Sql to other types

Tags: haskell, types, sqlite, hdbc

I have this:

```
import Database.HDBC.Sqlite3
import Database.HDBC
```

For converting fetched rows from a database I use this:

```
convertFromSql :: [SqlValue] -> [String]
convertFromSql [name, address, number, postal, city, country] = 
  [cName, cAddress, cNumber, cPostal, cCity, cCountry] where 
      cName     = (fromSql name) 
      cAddress  = (fromSql address) :: String 
      cNumber   = (fromSql number) :: String 
      cPostal   = (fromSql postal) :: String 
      cCity     = (fromSql city) :: String 
      cCountry  = (fromSql country) :: String
```

All works, but can I for example `map` the `fromSql` over the list of entries fetched from `sql`? And maybe a longshot: `zip` the mapped list with a list of types, so that code like above is more terse?

Comment: As simple as `convertFromSql = map fromSql`.

Comment: Although `fromSql :: Convertible SqlValue a => SqlValue -> a`, the fact that you have explicitly typed `convertFromSql` as `[SqlValue] -> [String]` means that `fromSql` will be specialized to `SqlValue -> String` when you apply it to the input list.

Comment: @Chepner: true, my bad considering (in this case) it is all `String`s

Comment: @arrowd: does not work, since the fetched rows are presented as a list of lists. Maybe with a double mapping. Will try.

Comment: @Madderote Yes, `map convertFromSql :: [[SqlValue]] -> [[String]]`.

Comment: @Chepner, yes, sorry. Thanks for adding that. Case closed :)